# Subtracting from a 'DateTime'

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to subtract from a `DateTime`. Example:

```
date1 = 13/01/2004 12:20:00
result = Subtract(date1-15);
```

Expected output:

```
13/01/2004 12:05:00
```

How do I do this?

Comment: @Will, why check Google when we have stackoverflow!

Comment: @code4life: Because it is a lazy exercise to ask a question about subtracting minutes, when you can add a negative amount of minutes. That is a pure mathematical exercise. IntelliSense provides the `AddMinutes()` method.

Comment: @Will - in that case we should recommend the OP uses IntelliSense, don't you agree?  Overall, stackoverflow > google, IMO... :)
          
(Or we should make it that way)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You may take a look at the [AddMinutes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addminutes.aspx) method:

```
var result = date1.AddMinutes(-15);
```

Comment: Be aware that calling `DateTime.AddMinutes(-1)` on a value that has been initialised to DateTime.MinValue throws an exception. Just be careful!

Comment: Just wanted to call out in a comment that there is .AddTicks, .AddMicroseconds, .AddMIlliseconds, .AddSeconds, .AddMinutes, .AddHours, .AddDays, .AddMonths, and .AddYears.

Answer (score 4):

Use `DateTime.Add(TimeSpan)` with a negative value.

Or use `DateTime.AddDays()`, `DateTime.AddMinutes()`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You could try this:

```
TimeSpan t1 = new TimeSpan(16,0,0);
DateTime d2= datetime.Subtract(t1);
```

Answer (score 1):

There's also this option:

```
TimeSpan timeToSubtract = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
DateTime result = date1.Subtract(timeToSubtract);
```